# .net: In a 3-layer Windows application Project, where it should be declared an EventArg class?

Tags: .net, events, layer, eventargs

In a 3-layer Windows application Project, where it should be declared an EventArg class?

Answer (score 1):

It depends which entities events belong to. If you have an event-driven domain model you may put them in the business logic layer. If you have events only in the UI you should put them in the presentation layer etc..